# How can I make this code more efficent for the coding challenge?

Tags: python

I am doing coding challenge named Integers: Recreation One in Codewars.

Challenge => Given two integers m, n (1 <= m <= n) we want to find all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square.

```
def list_squared(m, n):
    lst = list()
    for num in range(m, n+1):
        total= 0
        for i in range(1, num//2 +1):
            if num % i == 0:
                total += i**2
        total += num**2

        if (total**(1/2)) % 1 == 0:
            lst.append([num, total])

    return lst
```

My code works for sample tests but when I try to submit it, it is giving me " Execution Timed Out " error. I think I have to make this more efficent but don't know how to do it. How can I make the code more efficent?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It will not be faster, but I think the second loop should either be `range(1,num+1)`, or it should be `total+=i**2+(num/i)**2`, and subtract `num` at the end if it is a square number itself. The `total+=num**2` line feels wrong in both cases.

Comment: Ah, and with the `total+=i**2+(num/i)**2` variant, the inner loop should go not to `num/2`, but to `sqrt(num)`. I think that is where the thing can get faster.

Comment: @SuperKogito 1) that topic is `Ruby`, this question is `Python`. 2) the accepted answer in that topic is producing wrong results, which everyone seems to be completely happy with....

Comment: My bad,  I just read the problem and it was similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implementation of the `sqrt` idea:

```
def list_squared(m, n):
    lst = list()
    for num in range(m, n+1):
        total = 0
        sqrt = int(math.sqrt(num))
        for i in range(1, sqrt+1):
            q,r=divmod(num,i)
            if r == 0:
                total += i*i + q*q
        if sqrt*sqrt == num:
            total -= num

        if math.sqrt(total) % 1 == 0:
            lst.append([num, total])

    return lst
```

It seems to work. A couple things which may or may not make sense:

- I do not know if `**(1/2)` or `math.sqrt` performs better, it could be checked. However I feel `sqrt` is more readable. Of course if you are not allowed to use the math library, stick with `**`
- It is rather probable that `x*x` is faster than `x**2`, it could be checked too
- At assembly level, the quotient and the remainder are produced in a single step, which may or may not be true for Python. However this is why I used `divmod` (so `q*q` replaces `(num/i)*(num/i)`, or `(num/i)**2`)

In reality these details probably do not matter at all, shortening the inner loop should be the main trick.

---

@H.E.K.: you "felt" that the loop can be shortened somehow, via the `/2` thing, but in reality it has to be square root.
If `i` is divisor of `num`, `num/i` is also a divisor of `num`. And if `i` starts increasing from `1`, `num/i` starts decreasing from `num/1` (so from `num` itself). As time passes, they will meet somewhere, and that is `sqrt(num)`. Increasing `i` above `sqrt(num)` ends up with checking a divisor-pair which you have seen already.
An example with 20:

```
i   20/i
1   20
2   10
3   <something fraction>
4   5    <--- this is the last step when we encounter a new divisor
5   4    <--- here the divisors are "old", we have seen 4 and 5 already
6   <something fraction>
......
```

so the divisors are 1,20,2,10,4,5 - and we did not have to check 5...20 separately, it was enough to check `1...4=(int)sqrt(20)`, which is a significant gain.

Comment: that worked but I can't fully understand what did you do in the inner loop and after that. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @H.E.K ok, I added some explanation

Comment: @tevedamar thank you soo much. Now I fully understand what you did. Thank you again